# How to include HTML tags in JSON option passed to Jade Template?

Tags: pug

I am currently passing some variables to Jade Template but I found that when I try to passing HTML tags they will be changed into encoded strings like `&lt;div&gt;`

Is it possible to make those tags remain `<div>` after passed to Jade Template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `=` in Jade, content will be **escaped**
Example:

```
p= 'This code is' + ' <escaped>!'
```

Gives

```
<p>This code is &lt;escaped&gt;!</p>
```

You need to use `!=` in order to have content **unescaped**

Example:

```
p!= 'This code is <strong>not</strong> escaped!'
```

Gives

```
<p>This code is <strong>not</strong> escaped!</p>
```

Same happens to variables e.g.
escaped:

```
li Hello #{name}
```

unescaped:

```
li Hello !{name}
```

You can find more [here](http://jade-lang.com/reference/) - **Unescaped Buffered Code** section